# Fetch not including Cookies despite correctly configured options and CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cors, cross-domain, fetch-api

I have an backend server -- `https://b.com` -- and a client server -- `https://a.com`. I want to issue authenticated ajax requests from `a.com` to `b.com`.

Before the request is issued, the user will go to `b.com` and sign in. The session cookie will be stored in the browser with `HttpOnly`, `Secure` and `SameSite=None` options.

The `fetch()` requests on `a.com` are issued from a script with `type="module"` as such

```js
const res = await fetch("https://b.com", {
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
  credentials: "include",
});
```

And the backend is returning a response with the appropriate CORS headers. Namely

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: https://a.com
```

Nonetheless, the session cookie isn't being included in the `fetch()` request and, as such, authentication isn't working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is being done correctly. It turns out Chrome was blocking all third-party cookies.